# what does UnderlyingCriteria mean in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, orm

I am beginner in nhibernate and I just want to ask 
what does UnderlyingCriteria mean in nhibernate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In NHibernate 3.0 and newer, `QueryOver` is a strongly-typed wrapper for `Criteria`, one of NHibernate's oldest query interfaces (inherited from Java Hibernate)

The `UnderlyingCriteria` property provides access to the `ICriteria` instance that is being built.